# VB.NET getting errors on the statement of for each loop

Tags: vb.net, file-io, foreach

I coded a basic script to list all files in a directory using an `for each` loop as follows:

```
'imports system.io is required,
Dim test As String 'string
    On Error Resume Next 'error handling
    For Each file In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Program Files", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories) 'gets file pathfor each file in folder(s)
        test = test + file 'sets variable value to path
    Next 'loop until all files and sub-folders in the path have been searched
    RichTextBox1.Text =  test + " finished" 'show file names + path.
```

The problem arises when there is a denied access to a file, the error handler kicks in and ends the loop. Is there a method in getting the code to skip the current folder and going to the next one if an error occurs? I would have used an `try catch endtry` statement if the error happened within the loop, but as it occurs on the `for each` statement i supposed `On Error Resume Next` would work.

Comment: `On Error` exists for backwards compatibility only. It has no place in new vb.net code.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own enumeration:

```
Dim MoveResult As Boolean
Dim fileEnumerator = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Program Files", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).GetEnumerator()
Dim result As new StringBuilder()

Try
    MoveResult = fileEnumerator.MoveNext()
Catch
    MoveResult = True
End Try

While MoveResult
    result.Append(fileEnumerator.Current)

    Try
        MoveResult = fileEnumerator.MoveNext()
    Catch
        MoveResult = True
    End Try
End While

RichTextBox1.Text =  result.ToString() + " finished"
```

But this whole thing seems like a bad idea. Standard user accounts have limited access to the program files folder. It's been like this since Windows 2000, and for good reason. Nothing good will come from mucking around in there. At best, whatever you were hoping to accomplish by going through this folder will be undermined by skipping over the very files most likely to be of interest.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Unfortunately I still get an error, but on the `Dim fileEnumerator = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Program Files", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).GetEnumerator()` ,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are running into, but there are some examples here on how to do io here:

[How to do basic file I/O in Visual Basic 2005 or in Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304427/how-to-do-basic-file-i-o-in-visual-basic-2005-or-in-visual-basic-net)

> List files This sample code uses the GetFiles method of the Directory
>   class to get a list of files.

```
Dim file As String
Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(winDir)
For Each file In files
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(file)
Next
```

> Next Many things can go wrong when a user gains access to files. The
>   files may not exist, the files may be in use, or users may not have
>   rights on the files of folders that they are trying to access. It is
>   important to consider these possibilities when you write code and to
>   handle the exceptions that may be generated.